# How to display a token in plain text (without link)?

Tags: 8, webforms, tokens

I created a form with the module "Webform" on "Drupal 8".

In the form submission email, there is a token:

```
[webform_submission:values:profil:entity:field_personnel_sexe]
```

In the inbox, the term taxonomy displays a link. I want to display the text without the link.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the name of the term, use     `[webform_submission:values:profil:entity:field_personnel_sexe:name]`.

If you have another field for the *personnel_sexe*, for example you want to show the description, you can:

1. Change display for *Token*

   [image: Manage display fo token]
2. Use `[webform_submission:values:profil:entity:field_personnel_sexe:description]`
   as token for the description field

Comment: Thank you but it does not work. If I add `:name` the name you're not showing anymore

Comment: If you have an element in your webform called field_personnel_sexe you don't need to values profile entity, try with ` [webform_submission:values:field_personnel_sexs:name]`

Comment: It does not work. The token is displayed in the email but is not returned

Comment: Are you sure the element machine name is field_personnel_sexe ! I have tested it works

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question. It's a field in "Profile" that refers to taxonomy

Comment: So you want to send sexe of connected user, who submit the webform ?

Comment: i test with `[webform_submission:values:profil:entity:field_personnel_sexe]` there is no available token like this, if you want current user try with token `[current-user:field_personnel_sexe]`

Answer (score 3):

I'm might be late to the game but after way too long, I was able to get a Taxonomy Term without a link using this. I needed this in a hidden field.

`[webform_submission:source-entity:field_department_owner:entity:name]`

`[webform_submission:source-entity:FIELDMACHINENAME:entity:name]`

So now instead of this `<a href="/taxonomy/term/4" hreflang="en">Computer Science</a>` in my webform submissions, I get `Computer Science`.

Since I tried the solution in this ticket numerous times with failure, I thought this would be a good place to log this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can you **:htmldecode:striptags** at the end of your token.

Care of the security (seen on the token tree page) :

> This suffix has security implications.
>   Use :htmldecode with :striptags.
>   :striptags removes all HTML tags from returned value.